# update(s) vs. upgrade(s)

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Consider the following tags:

- [upgrade](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrade)
- [update](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update)
- [updates](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/updates)

They all appear to be questions about moving from one version of Android to a newer version.

Which should be the master tag?

Related, what about questions about upgrading applications. [app-upgrades](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/app-upgrades) perhaps? Do we need [os-update](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/os-update)?

([upgrades](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrades) has no questions at the moment, but I'd expect it to be a synonym for [upgrade](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrade) or vice versa.)

Comment: I'm not sure I'd bother distinguishing between various types of updates.  If we want to reserve `updates` for OS updates only, I'd be inclined to just remove the tag entirely from app-update questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm inclined to go with [update] as the master tag. "Upgrade", to me, implies a voluntary purchase of a newer version. "Update" is what you do when your carrier/manufacturer releases a newer version; you don't get much choice in the matter. There are also those occasional updates that remove functionality, which is not an upgrade.

Besides, [update] currently has, by far, the most questions.

(Obviously rooters/modders are different, but they're a minority of Android users.)

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: Agreed, sounds good to me too.

Comment: How about people that want to revert to older version of Android/app? Those are usually called downgrade, not downdate.

Comment: @Lie: Fair point, and [tag:downgrade] seems like a reasonable tag to have.